# block a function when argument type does not belong to a set of types

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae, type-traits

In a specific requirement I need to allow instantiation of a template function `func` only for a specific set of allowed types.

Therefore I tried to use already available `std::type_traits` and then used `std::enable_if` to block instantiation. Here is my implementation.

```
// C++17
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using my_int_t      = std::int16_t;         // T1
using my_string_t   = std::string;          // T2
using my_vec_t      = std::vector<int>;     // T3
// and so on .. a long list of types 


/* Check input Type T : if it belongs to {T1,T2,T3} 
If it belongs then only allow this version of func to instantiate
*/
template<typename T, typename T1,typename T2,typename T3>
using isCompatible = std::bool_constant<std::is_same_v<T,T1>
                            || std::is_same_v<T,T2>
                            || std::is_same_v<T,T3> >;

template<typename T>
using CompatibleTypeCheck = std::enable_if_t< isCompatible<std::remove_reference_t<T>,
                                                    my_int_t,
                                                    my_string_t,
                                                    my_vec_t>::value >;



template<typename T,
        typename = CompatibleTypeCheck<T>>
void func(T&& val) {
    std::cout <<"Hello from Generic Func" << std::endl;
}


int main() {

    // int z = 10;   
    // func(z); // Error ! as expected

    my_int_t w = 100;
    func(w); // OK
}
```

But the problem is there are too many allowed types. Is there is better way to clean both of the alias templates ? i.e. `isCompatible` and `CompatibleTypeCheck`.

If there is any better "idiomatic" way to achieve the same result, please suggest it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write `isCompatible` like this:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Ts> 
using isCompatible = std::bool_constant<(std::is_same_v<T,Ts> || ...)>;
```

There's not much you can do for `CompatibleTypeCheck` since you need to specify all the allowed types somewhere.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bW95hT).

---

Note that `enable_if` is usually used when you want to enable or disable particular overloads. In your case, the easier way would be to just `static_assert` inside the function definition:

```
template<typename T>
void func(T&& val) {
    static_assert(isCompatible<std::remove_reference_t<T>,
                                                    my_int_t,
                                                    my_string_t,
                                                    my_vec_t>::value);
    std::cout <<"Hello from Generic Func" << std::endl;
}
```

which avoids the need for `CompatibleTypeCheck` entirely.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G447sq).